# Why is the ![] == {} and {} == ![] result is different

Tags: javascript

I can understand `[] ==! []` is correct, `{} ==! {}` is wrong, because `toPrimitive([])` returns '' and `toPrimitive({})` returns `[object object]`, `''== 0`, and `[object object] != 0`. Same reason, I also can understand `![] == {}` returns false, but I wonder why `{} == ![]` report `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ==`? Shouldn't the result also be false?

[image]

Comment: Because in the second case `{}` is a code block, not an object.

Comment: I would mark this as a duplicate but due to bad search capabilities im unable to find it.

Comment: I suppose this has to do with JS interpreting `{}` as an empty block rather than an empty object, by default. `({}) == ![]` should give the proper result.

Comment: @quentin there are better dupes out there that explain the behaviour in the JS console. `{} == {}` would otherwise be a syntax error too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the problem is that `{}` got two meanings in JS:

`{ let a = 1; }` is a *block statement*

`{ a: 1 }` is an *object literal expression*

it will choose which to take wether it expects an expression or a statement. In your case, it is in a statement context, so `{}` is treated as a block statement, and therefore throws an error.

Now you could ask "Why does it accept `{} == {}` though?"

Well that's because your console sometimes evaluates the entered code as an *expression* and sometimes as a *statement*. I'ts rule is basically: If the code starts with `{` and ends with `}` it is parsed as an *expression* (it is wrapped in `(` ). So when you type:

```
 { a: 1 }
```

that would actually be a SyntaxError in JS, as `:` is not defined inside a block statement, therefore the console is so nice to wrap it as:

```
({ a: 1})
```

the same happens with

```
{} == {}
// wrapped as
({} == {})
```

but this:

```
{} == []
```

does not fullfill the condition, the whole thing gets treated as a statement, `{}` is treated as a block statement.

Comment: But why {} in ![]=={} is not treated as a code block? @Jonas Wilms

Comment: @DangoSky cause the `!` always starts an expression